# How to use variables in in a Ecto query in where clause

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a map :

```
  allowed_lookup = %{coordinate: "15.0", id: 1}
```

I want to use this map to make a Ecto query to filter out some entries in database.

I am thinking something like this :

```
Enum.reduce(allowed_lookup, Project.Models.Grid,
            fn {x,y}, query ->
                IO.puts "#{inspect x} , #{inspect y}"
                query = where(query, [q] , q.x == ^y)
            end)

queryset = Project.Repo.all(query)
```

So It will recursively apply all the filters present in map to get a queryset. 
But this code is not valid as q.x is not getting converted to q.coordinate or q.id .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
allowed_lookup = %{coordinate: "15.0", id: 1}
Enum.reduce(allowed_lookup, Project.Models.Grid,
        fn {x,y}, query ->
            IO.puts "#{inspect x} , #{inspect y}"

            field_query = [{x, y}] #dynamic keyword list

            query|>where(^field_query)
        end)

queryset = Project.Repo.all(query)
```

`Ecto.Query.where` accepts a keyword list where the field given as key is going to be compared with the given value. In this case using the simple `[key: value]` construct for keyword list will not work since the field and value are dynamic. However, keyword list can also be constructed, dynamically, as list of tuple like `[{key, value}]`.

```
 iex> [{:a, 1}] == [a: 1] # true
```